# Powershell update existing user in the people or group field

Tags: powershell

I want to update the user of a people or group field. The property allow multiple users to set for this field. How can I keep the users who are already present in this field and update the existing user using Powershell script?

For e.g I have user1,user2,user3 in the people or group field. Now I want to update user1 to user4.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to read the column value first and then add new values then update.

**Get Multi-valued People Picker Field Value (if Allow multiple selections enabled!) using PowerShell:**

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Variables
        $SiteURL = "<replace site url>"
        $ListName = "Tasks"               
        $FieldName="Assigned To"


    #Get site and List objects
    $web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
    $list= $web.lists[$listName]

    #Iterate through each row in the list
    foreach ($Item in $list.Items)
    {
        if($item[$FieldName])
        {
            #Get People picker field values collection
            $UserCollection = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection($Web,$item[$FieldName].ToString())
            Write-host Item ID: $item["ID"]

            #Get each User from the Person or Group field
            foreach($User in $UserCollection)
            {
                 #Get the Display Name of the user
                 Write-host $User.LookupValue 
                 #Get the Login Name (Account ID)
                 Write-host $User.User
                 #Get the E-mail
                 Write-host $User.User.Email             
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update Multiple Values People Picker Field using PowerShell script**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Variables
$SiteURL = "http://portal.crescent.com/sites/Sales"
$ListName = "Tasks"               
$FieldName="Assigned To"

#Get site and List objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$list= $web.lists[$listName]

#Get the List Item to update
$ListItem  = $List.GetItemByID(2)

#User Account to set
$UserAccounts="Crescent\Salaudeen; Crescent\Ravi"
$UserAccountsColl = $UserAccounts -split ';'

$UserCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection
foreach($UserAccount in $UserAccountsColl)
{
    #Get the User
    $User=$web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)

    #Add to collection
    $UserFieldValue = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($Web, $User.ID, $User.LoginName)
    $UserCollection.Add($UserFieldValue)
}

#update the Multiple value Person or Group field
$ListItem[$FieldName] = $UserCollection
$ListItem.Update()
```

**Source**: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/get-set-person-or-group-people-picker-field-values-using-powershell.html

Comment: This works fine for single user but for multiple user I am getting this error
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid look-up value. A look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again."
Please refer this link:  http://3d-grphique.blogspot.in/2015/03/set-multi-user-field-in-sharepoint.html
I am facing the same problem.

Comment: It looks like you have copied at least the most of this answer from the following blog post: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/get-set-person-or-group-people-picker-field-values-using-powershell.html. When using someone's work, it's **always** important to mention the original author/source. I have edited your answer to give an example how this could be done in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I have write code, It is not the full code, but may be it will help you to move forward

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$webUrl = "http://localSite"
$library = "Sports" 
$s = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)    
$w = $s.OpenWeb()         
$l = $w.Lists[$library] 

Write-Host   "Connecting to site" $webUrl 
foreach ($listItem in $l.Items)
 {
  #Get Multiple Users from list column 
  $MultipleUsers=$listItem["Users"] 

  #Remove the User 1 from above variable, write some code for this 

  #then add users one by one in below 

  [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection]$lotsofpeople = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection            


  $user1 = $w.EnsureUser("User2");            
  $user1Value = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($w,     
  $user1.Id, $user1.LoginName) 
  $lotsofpeople.Add($user1Value); 

  $user2 = $w.EnsureUser("User3");            
  $user1Value = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($w,   
  $user2.Id, $user2.LoginName) 
  $lotsofpeople.Add($user2Value); 

  $user3 = $w.EnsureUser("User4");            
  $user1Value = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($w,  
  $user3.Id, $user3.LoginName) 
  $lotsofpeople.Add($user3Value); 

  #then update current Item Users with new values 

  $listItem["Users"]= lotsofpeople
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are defining the the user Collection as below

```
   [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection]$ItemSPuserList = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection
```